# get checked check-box value using form-collection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have check-box input field on the view page as given below-

```
<input type=@item.InputType.ToString().Trim().ToLower() id="@item.AdminAnswers.ElementAt(i).Answer" value="@item.AdminAnswers.ElementAt(i).Answer" name="@item.Id"></input>@item.AdminAnswers.ElementAt(i).Answer
```

and in the controller am getting data using form collection as given below-

```
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection data)
    {
        foreach (var item in surveyDatas)
        {           
            if(item.InputType.ToString().Trim().ToLower() == "checkbox")
            {
                var dev =item.NumberOfChoice;
                for (int i = 1; i < dev; i++)
                {
                    //here I need to iterate checked checkbox value
                }
            }
            myclientanswer.DevAnswers = devAnswer;              
            clientAnswer.Add(myclientanswer);
        }
        return View("LoginResult");
    }
```

How can I iterate only checked check-box values over there??

Comment: Please research how to use a proper ViewModel class. Once you understand that, anything you want to do becomes easier and better to understand. My advice is to never use FormCollection, it shows either lack of understanding, lack of interest or lack of effort, and worse it leads to all kinds of effort needed only to fix the bad path that you are following. E.g. see Microsoft Virtual Academy for MVC tutorials.

Comment: @PeterB actually I am using one model to generate the whole form means Input fields.So to get all the values from there I have to use the form-collection.

Comment: "I have to use the form-collection" has never been a true statement in MVC.

Comment: @PeterB then what Should I use for these?? because I want to get all the form data into different model. how it can be done?

Comment: See the answer by Rica, it shows what approach to use. A good start is to use the same ViewModel in the View to generate controls *and* in the Action Method parameter - doing so allows MVC Model Binding (please google that!) to do all the form parsing for you. And then FormCollection can be forgotten. Maybe I had a good teacher, but I never knew of FormCollection until I saw it appear on Stack Overflow in all kinds of messy scenarios...

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you do it using htmlhelpers and models.Check this out if it might be of any help..

```
 public class UserModel
  {
    public List<Requirements> Requirements { get; set; }
  }
 public class Requirements
  {
    public int RId { get; set; }
    public string RName { get; set; }
    public bool RIsSelected { get; set; }
  }
 public class Pdf
  {
    public int PId { get; set; }
    public int RId { get; set; }
    public string Requirement { get; set; }
  }
```

View will be

```
@model.usermodel
  @using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))
    {
      @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Requirements.Count; i++)
        {
          @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Requirements[i].RId)        
          @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Requirements[i].RIsSelected, new { id = "requirements_" + i, @class = "divider" })            
          @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Requirements[i].RName, new { @class = "divider", style = "display:inline;font-family: Courier New, Courier, monospace;" })          
        }
 <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" name="Command" />
}
```

Controller code

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult About(List<Requirements> requirements,Usermodel model)
  {
    var id = model.id;
       List<Pdf> plist = new List<Pdf>();        
        foreach (var item in requirements)
        {
          Pdf p = new Pdf();
          if (item.RIsSelected == true)
          {
           p.PId = id;
           p.RId = item.RId;
           plist.Add(p);         
         }
      }
```

Comment: @user3235118 add all the other input fields into usermodel itself.Usermodel is the main model.