# Select Multiple Checkboxes on MVC form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

I have a model called AnswerSheet, it is a bunch of String Answers.  Snip below:

```
public class PassengerAnswerSheet
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Question 1")]
        public string Q1 { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Question 2")]
        public string Q2 { get; set; }
```

For each answer, I have multiple checkboxes, I want the answer to be a string generated by the selected checkboxes text.

The checkboxes are built using a different model, an animal for this example:

```
public class Animal
    {
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Currently I can get the Question to display what I want (sort of) using this code on my Razor Form:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Q1, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @foreach(var  animal in Curbside.Helpers.AnswerLists.CreateAnimalsList())
                {
                    string Hi = (animal.Name);  
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(item => animal.IsChecked)
                    @Hi 
                    <br />
                }
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Q1)                
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Q1)
            </div>
        </div>
```

Now what I need to figure out, is how to have the checked boxes for the "Foreach" section generate a string when  the user submits a form, example it will generate "Cow, Pig" as the answer for Q1 if the user has checked the boxes beside Cow and Pig.  I've been reading a lot on this but haven't figured it out, and I feel stuck here.  Will continue to investigate.  Obviously I need ot get rid of @Html.EditorFor but I don't know what to replace it with or how to use it.

Comment: The first thing you should be doing is creating a view model to represent what you want to display (something along the lines of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28055287/asp-net-mvc-5-group-of-radio-buttons/28057533#28057533))

Comment: Even if i create a viewmodel I will still be facing the same problem.  I'll create a viewmodel and try this just to be sure.  I've found multiple different ways to display what i want, the problem is on SUBMIT how do I get it to save the selected boxes.

Comment: If you use a view model you will not be facing any problems :)

Comment: And as a  side note, you cannot use a `foreach` loop to generate form controls for a collection (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943))

Comment: Check this link if it might be of any help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36981588/get-checked-check-box-value-using-form-collection/36984315#36984315 and also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624762/performing-httppost-to-store-checkbox-selected-values-in-database